# Pasting long numbers from SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an issue pasting long numbers from SQL Server into Excel. The numbers exceed Excel's digits of precision limitation 
(ex. 123343210000000000001).

When pasted, Excel rounds the number down to 123343210000000000000. I have tried pulling the data as

`SELECT ''''+convert(nvarchar(max),long_number_column)`

so the data pulls as '123343210000000000001.

Once pasted in Excel, the number is displayed as 
'123343210000000000001.

I was hoping that the apostrophe would disappear, as it would if you manually typed it into Excel. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't pull the extra single quote in your query. Go to excel and set the format of the cell to text before you paste in your values. Otherwise excel will make an assumption that the values are numbers.

Comment: @SeanLange is exactly right, you should set the numeric formats (with TEXT being one of those formats) in Excel *prior* to pasting things in.  It especially likes to convert things into dates.

Comment: Thanks to both! The very simple/easy solution I was looking for. Appreciated!